# How to scale the dataGridView size to form when the form size change?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am changed the anchor of the gridview to auto-scale the form size whenever the form size change.

However, this setting did well on other form,But this grid view is going out the bound of the form. How can I fix this problem?

Here is the setting:

[image]

[image]

---

Solution:
1. Use a panel to store the items first. (button, textbox,gridview etc.)
2. Set the panel `dock->fill`
3. Set the items `anchor`
4. fixed

Comment: The solution is right under your nose: **`Dock`** option.

Comment: sorry for misleading. I want to make the grid view auto-scale when I scale the form.

Comment: You could perhaps achieve that by using a docked grid inside a panel, and that panel being docked in the form. Add a padding to this panel and whenever you resize the form, so will the grid. Responsivity in winforms really sucks.

Comment: Good suggestion! I will try it.

Comment: This really should not happen. So there must be be another spot the messes with the DGV's size.

Comment: Yes... there should have a conflict setting. Still finding.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property of your DataGridView to:

```
Anchor: Top, Bottom, Left, Right
```

However, if you want to fill the entire form and at the same time have the grid adjusts to the form size, then you could use:

```
Dock: Fill
```

Comment: sorry for misleading. I want to make the grid view auto-scale when I scale the form.

Comment: So whenever you resize the form, the grid will also adjust right?. Is that what you're trying to achieve?. If so, then the first suggestion would do the trick

Comment: Yes. I am using this setting in all grid view(the grid views on the other forms is working well.), but this grid view get out this problem. Only this grid view

Comment: I see. What grid view is it?. If it didn't work with the grid settings then you can move into the programmatic approach. Ping me up, maybe I could give a hand in debugging.

Comment: Just a `Form.dataGridView`, there should have a conflict setting that cause the problem. Still finding where is the setting get this wrong.